# Get lowered function name from lambda

Tags: c#, lambda, code-generation, roslyn

Is it possible with Roslyn to get to the name of compiler generated lambda methods?

For example imagine the following class:

```
public sealed class Foo   
{
    public void Bar()
    {
        Func<int, int> func = x =>
        {
            if (x > 0)
            {
                return x;
            }
            return -x;
        };
    }
}
```

the following Code is generated:

```
public sealed class Foo
{
    [CompilerGenerated]
    [Serializable]
    private sealed class <>c
    {
        public static readonly Foo.<>c <>9 = new Foo.<>c();
        public static Func<int, int> <>9__0_0;
        internal int <Bar>b__0_0(int x)
        {
            bool flag = x > 0;
            int result;
            if (flag)
            {
                result = x;
            }
            else
            {
                result = -x;
            }
            return result;
        }
    }
    public void Bar()
    {
        Func<int, int> arg_20_0;
        if ((arg_20_0 = Foo.<>c.<>9__0_0) == null)
        {
            Foo.<>c.<>9__0_0 = new Func<int, int>(Foo.<>c.<>9.<Bar>b__0_0);
        }
    }
}
```

Roslyn contains the code that is responsible for lowering the lambda into methods with different strategies depending on the circumstance ([all here](https://github.com/dotnet/roslyn/tree/master/src/Compilers/CSharp/Portable/Lowering/LambdaRewriter)).

But is there any simple way to get the name `Foo.<>c.<Bar>b__0_0` if I have the symbol or the SimpleLambdaExpressionSyntax node?

This is obviously implementation specific behavior, so this would require using the same roslyn version the compiler is using, but that'd be an acceptable.

Comment: The same code isn't necessarily going to have the same name each time you compile it, even if you use the same version of the compiler.

Comment: @Servy Looking at the code in `GeneratedNames.cs` I don't see how that would be possible without changing the code in some form? Or can the ordinal vary depending on compile order? The way I read the documentation on `DebugId` I would've expected that to not be the case.

Comment: And yet in the next version they might use a random number instead, for example.  And the current code will result in the name being based on the order in which the method bodies are codegened, so if the order of the methods isn't static (which there is no reason that it has to be) then you get a different name.

Comment: @Servy I already explicitly said that this is an implementation detail which requires keeping it in sync. And does the DebugId now currently really vary or is that another "they could change it in the future" possibility?

Comment: It's both.  It's absolutely not something that you should be relying on at all.  You're simply setting yourself up for a world of hurt.  If you want a function to have a reliable name then *use a named function* rather than an anonymous function.  Only use an anonymous function if you don't care about what the name is at all.

Comment: @Servy That's not particularly relevant when trying out code analyses on existing code. Clearly things that might not be relevant for the developer can be quite relevant for other things. Also in what circumstance is the DebugId not fixed? Looking at the code they use a new `ArrayBuilder<LambdaDebugInfo>` for every method compilation and compiling a single method is a sequential process, so how could the debug ID possibly vary?

Answer (score 1):

It is not possible with the Roslyn APIs.  You can use something like [System.Reflection.Metadata](https://www.nuget.org/packages/System.Reflection.Metadata) to read the IL and find the names if you need to.  However it should be said that the names the compiler generates are an implementation detail and they will change.